# Why does this ansible lineinfile task always trigger a notify?

Tags: ansible

The following task always triggers a notify

The first time it runs ansible applies the change which is expected,
and the line is changed. 
If I run it again, ansible considers it as "changed", even though
the regex cannot possibly match, since the line has become 
"bind-address   = 0.0.0.0"

why ?

```
  - name: Ensure MySQL will listen on all ip interfaces (bind to 0.0.0.0)
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      regexp='bind-address\s*=\s*127\.0\.0\.1\s*'
      line='bind-address   = 0.0.0.0'
      state=present
      insertafter=EOF
    notify: restart mysql
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Refer to [the `backrefs` option](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) of the `lineinfile` module. Specifically, "*if the regexp doesn't match anywhere in the file, the file will be left unchanged*." A working play would look like this:

```
- name: Ensure MySQL will listen on all ip interfaces (bind to 0.0.0.0)
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    regexp='bind-address\s*=\s*127\.0\.0\.1\s*'
    line='bind-address   = 0.0.0.0'
    state=present
    backrefs=yes
  notify: restart mysql
```